# Confused about applying Routh Hurwitz to $s^2 +s + k$

Tags: transfer-function, control-systems

I have a closed loop transfer function 
$$G_{\rm cl}(s) = \frac{k}{s^{2} + s + k}$$
I am trying to find the critical gain of the system. From using the Routh Hurwitz criterion I get a $k = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

Second order Routh Hurwitz:

$$a_0s^2+a_1s+a_2 = 0$$

$$\begin{cases}
s^2 & a_0 & a_2\\
s^1 & a_1 & 0\\
s^0 & a_2\\
\end{cases}$$

In your example

$$\begin{cases}
s^2 & 1 & k\\
s^1 & 1 & 0\\
s^0 & k\\
\end{cases}$$

Hence, $k$ should be positive.